# Textbox to accept value 100 and above

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

This is my textbox that I have:

[image: textbox]

This is the code for it :

```
        <!-- Preferred credit limit --> 
        <div class="signup-card-section">
            <h2 class="accordion-header boldtext">Tell Us Your Preferred Credit Limit</h2>
            <div class="column-control no-padding twelve colgrid">
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="row">
                        <p class="text-red">(Choose one)</p>
                        <p>My Preferred Credit Limit<span class="text-red">*</span></p>
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="prefcreditlimit" checked="checked" value="yesprefcreditlimit" id="yesprefcreditlimit"> 
                        <span class="radiotextdeco">S$</span> <input type="text" class="input numeric-only nodecimal width30" name="prefcreditlimitval" id="prefcreditlimit" min="100"> <span style="font-size:12px;"> (Must be in multiples of 00’ and a minimum of S$100)</span><br><br>
                        <input type="radio" name="prefcreditlimit" checked="checked" value="noprefcreditlimit"> <span class="radiotextdeco">I dont have a preferred credit limit and agree to any credit limit determined</span><br><br>
                        <p><strong>Note:</strong> Principal applicant and Suplementary applicant will be granted the preferred credit limit of any limit determined by the bank, whichever is lower.</p>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Error message to appear if value key in is not in multiples of 00’ or minimum of S$100: “Your Preferred Credit Limit must be in multiple of 00’ and a minimum of S$100. 
Since I set the min value to 100. There's an error message appear when user enters less 100. The problem is now, I'm not sure how to check for the validation of 00'

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: on value change event check what value has been entered. If its not multiple of 100 then show the error.

Comment: Where is the js code? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Is your question how to check or the math to check if it's multiple of 100?

Comment: Are you struggling with the logic?

Comment: I want to check if the value entered by user has multiple 00 and set a minimum of 100. if the user entered less than 100 an error will show up. but if the user entered more than 100 but there's no multiples of 00s then that's where the validation comes in.

Comment: @rory-h You mean mulitples of 100. Eg. 100 x 100 or 100 x 10 ?

Comment: Checking the last two digits are 00s or not. so the regex I'm guessing is ^\d+00$ ?

Answer (score 3):

Use `<input type="number">` along with the `min` and `step` attributes:

```
<input type="number" name="prefcreditlimitval" min="100" step="100">
```

If the user enters a value lower than the min or something that isn't a multiple of step, the browser's validation will prevent the form from being submitted.  In browsers that don't support validation, you can use a polyfill (like [this one](https://github.com/chemerisuk/better-form-validation/)).

You can test out the validation (though SO doesn't allow forms to run):

```css
input:invalid {
    border-color: red;
}
```

```html
Input multiples of 100<br><br>
<input type="number" name="test" min="100" step="100">
```

Answer (score 1):

Input tag also has 'pattern' attribute, where you can specify Regex pattern to check input.
So something like

```
<input type="text" class="input numeric-only nodecimal width30" name="prefcreditlimitval" id="prefcreditlimit" min="100" pattern="\d+00$">
```

should work!
[Some info about input's pattern attr](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp)

Comment: I'm thinking of not using pattern but instead a function with that regex to check the user's input. I think pattern is not supported by alot of browsers. How can I do that?

Comment: Same as mentioned in niyasc's answer -  `function validate() {
  var value = $("#prefcreditlimit").val();
  if (/\d+00$/.test(value)) {
    alert("Please provide a valid input");
    $("#prefcreditlimit").val("");
  }
}`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answers, you may use `min` and `step` attributes to limit value of input field. But these attributes were introduced as a part of **HTML 5** standards and it is not supported in all browsers yet.

A generic solution using jQuery/JS to check input value and give error message if it does not meet your requirements can be written as follows.

```js
function validate() {
  var value = $("#prefcreditlimit").val();
  if (isNaN(value) || value < 100 || value % 100 != 0) {
    alert("Please provide a valid input");
    $("#prefcreditlimit").val("");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="radiotextdeco">S$</span> 
<input type="text" class="input numeric-only nodecimal width30" name="prefcreditlimitval" id="prefcreditlimit" min="100" onblur="validate()"> <span style="font-size:12px;"> (Must be in multiples of 00’ and a minimum of S$100)</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add some validation in Javascript, checking whether the input is indeed a number, if so then check if it's also at least 100 and if so, check if the input is a multitude of 100. You can do it like this:

```
var val = parseInt($("#prefcreditlimit").val(), 10);
if (isNaN(val))
{
    // ERROR; NOT A NUMBER
}
else if (val < 100)
{
    // ERROR; VALUE IS LOWER THAN 100
}
else if (val % 100 !== 0)
{
    // ERROR; VALUE IS NOT A MULTITUDE OF 100
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want the value to be greater than 100 and a multiple of 100. Seeing as you have tagged the question with jQuery I have done a jQuery example for you.

I am listening for changes on the textfield using [.change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/).

```
jQuery("#prefcreditlimit").change(function () { ... });
```

I am using `jQuery(this).val();` or `jQuery("#prefcreditlimit").val();` to get the current value of the textfield [.val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/)

From your comments, I have updated to first check that the radio button is checked first using `!jQuery("#yesprefcreditlimit").is(':checked')` which says if the checkbox is not checked.

Then I use simple logic checks first checking if the value is a number `isNaN(value)` then if `value < 100` is less than 100. Then if `value % 100 > 0` if the [modulus](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/what-is-modular-arithmetic) of the value is greater than 100.

There definitely a lot more you could go here, and a lot of different ways you could do this, this is just one way. For example you might not want the change part of this and instead do the validation on the submit of the form.

Note: In the stack snippet you need to click out of the textbox for the change event to be triggered.

```js
jQuery(function () {
  jQuery("#prefcreditlimit").change(function () {
    var value = jQuery(this).val();
    
    if(!jQuery("#yesprefcreditlimit").is(':checked')) {
        jQuery("#warning").text("");
        return;
    }

    if(isNaN(value)) {
        jQuery("#warning").text("Value is not a number.");
        return;
    }
    
    if(value < 100) {
        jQuery("#warning").text("Value is less than 100");
        return;
    }
    
    if(value % 100 > 0) {
        jQuery("#warning").text("Value needs to be a multiple of 100");
        return;
    }
    
    jQuery("#warning").text("Value: " + value + " is Okay!");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>My Preferred Credit Limit<span class="text-red">*</span></p>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="prefcreditlimit" checked="checked" value="yesprefcreditlimit" id="yesprefcreditlimit"> 
<span class="radiotextdeco">S$</span> <input type="text" name="prefcreditlimitval" id="prefcreditlimit" min="100"> <span style="font-size:12px;"> (Must be in multiples of 00’ and a minimum of S$100)</span><br><br>
<input type="radio" name="prefcreditlimit" checked="checked" value="noprefcreditlimit"> <span class="radiotextdeco">I dont have a preferred credit limit and agree to any credit limit determined</span><br><br>
<p id="warning"></p>
```

Comment: is there any way at I can use regex instead?  regex: ^\d+00$

Comment: You could but this allows you to show different error messages: text instead of a number; if the value is to low; then if its not the correct multiple.

Comment: onchange doesnt seem to work. As when I click on the radio button the warning Value is not a number is there forever

Comment: Then you need to put some extra logic in place, to check if the radio button you wish to check for is checked.

Answer (score -1):

If you have no problem using input type number you can use, `step` attribute

`step = "any"` or positive floating-point number NEW specifies the value granularity of the element’s value.

If step is not explicitly included, the value of step defaults to 1, as if it were included with step="1" (or `step="100"` in the case of `type="time"`), even if the default value or min value is a float.

```
<input type="number" class="input numeric-only nodecimal width30" name="prefcreditlimitval" id="prefcreditlimit" min="100" step="100">
```

Comment: Will you say that the answer is already given? I started typing the answer and in b/w I was just browsing for the definition of the step and by the time I updated the answer, I have seen that that sort of answer is already give, also as I have 2-3 points defining what step is, I found this answer useful and left it undeleted. If the answer is wrong, you can downvote it. whats the reason here?